# Why Use JavaScript in Less.js

Tags: javascript, css, less

Why would you use JavaScript within a Less.js file when every example and explanation I've seen talk about compiling it server side and serving it as a cached CSS file. I have not seen a single example of JavaScript being used, rather than it can, and 'here is some random JavaScript in a Less file, see? It works!'.

Is the idea here, that you would have two Less files, one which contains all the styling and is served as a cached CSS file (fast serving), the other would contain any (and much fewer) dynamic, client specific calculations, as well as any styling done by JavaScript (longer to serve, but less of it) - The Less files now containing everything to do with styling (rather than it being split between your CSS and JS files)?

Or is this more of just a 'Look it can parse JavaScript' gimmick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you compile server-side, it uses node, so JavaScript still gets executed, just not in the context of the browser.

I would recommend never using it as it mixes technologies and makes the file look messy. however sometimes its required, for example converting @arguments to a comma seperated format or doing substring - anything you get stuck on doing in less and need.

but if you can do it without js, then do it without.